# Java 8 : grouping field values by field names

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to find a more elegant way to create a map that group field values by field names using Java 8 than the following:

```
@Test
public void groupFieldValuesByFieldNames() {
    Person lawrence = aPerson().withFirstName("Lawrence").withLastName("Warren").born();
    Person gracie = aPerson().withFirstName("Gracie").withLastName("Ness").born();

    Map<String, List<String>> valuesByFieldNames = new HashMap<>();
    Stream.of(lawrence, gracie).forEach(person -> {
        valuesByFieldNames.computeIfAbsent("lastName", s -> new ArrayList<>()).add(person.getLastName());
        valuesByFieldNames.computeIfAbsent("firstName", s -> new ArrayList<>()).add(person.getFirstName());
    });

    assertThat(valuesByFieldNames, hasEntry("lastName", asList("Warren", "Ness")));
    assertThat(valuesByFieldNames, hasEntry("firstName", asList("Lawrence", "Gracie")));
}
```

Comment: If you feel obligated to do something like this, I'd start with `Map<String, Function<Person, String>>` that mapped each field name to a getter for that field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
Map<String, List<String>> valuesByFieldNames = Stream.of(lawrence, gracie)
    .flatMap(p -> Stream.of(new String[]{"firstName", p.getFirstName()},
                            new String[]{"lastName", p.getLastName()}))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(a -> a[0],
             Collectors.mapping(a -> a[1], Collectors.toList())));
```

Or more generally

```
Map<String, List<String>> valuesByFieldNames = Stream.of(lawrence, gracie)
    .flatMap(p -> Stream.of(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>("firstName", p.getFirstName()),
                            new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>("lastName", p.getLastName())))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getKey(),
             Collectors.mapping(e -> e.getValue(), Collectors.toList())));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have the following, that will work correctly in parallel:

```
Map<String, List<String>> valuesByFieldNames = 
    Stream.of(lawrence, gracie).collect(HashMap::new, (m, p) -> {
        m.computeIfAbsent("lastName", s -> new ArrayList<>()).add(p.getLastName());
        m.computeIfAbsent("firstName", s -> new ArrayList<>()).add(p.getFirstName());
    }, (m1, m2) -> m2.forEach((k, v) -> m1.merge(k, v, (l1, l2) -> { l1.addAll(l2); return l1; })));
```

What this does is that it collect each person into a [mutable `HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#MutableReduction). The accumulator computes the last name and the first name by invoking `computeIfAbsent`, just like your initial code. The combiner merges two maps together by iterating over the entries of the second map and merging each key into the first map; in case of conflict, the value is the addition of the two lists.